# C# NanoVG Transparency issue

Tags: c#, opentk

Hi I'm trying to change from Cairo (2D Vector image library) to NanoVG.
I'm using C#, openTK and Nano.VG.NET to make my game.

I'm having issues with alpha? Transparency/Blending is an issue…

Here is an output

Without NanoVG Overlay :

[image]

With NanoVG Overlay :

[image]

I think it has to do with blending or the nano shader….Not sure. Does anyone knows how to solve this?

My OpenGL Initialization :

```
GL.DrawBuffer (DrawBufferMode.Back);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.Lighting);
GL.Enable (EnableCap.Texture2D);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.Multisample);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.SampleAlphaToCoverage);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.AlphaTest);
GL.DepthFunc (DepthFunction.Lequal);
GL.Enable (EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.ScissorTest);
GL.Enable ( EnableCap.TextureRectangle);

GL.Enable (EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc (BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution.

For Anyone Having this problem just Add GL.Enable (EnableCap.StencilTest);

```
internal static void InitializeOpenGL ()
{
GL.DrawBuffer (DrawBufferMode.Back);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.Lighting);
GL.Enable (EnableCap.Texture2D);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.Multisample);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.SampleAlphaToCoverage);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.AlphaTest);
GL.DepthFunc (DepthFunction.Lequal);
GL.Enable (EnableCap.DepthTest);
GL.Enable (EnableCap.StencilTest);
GL.Disable (EnableCap.ScissorTest);
GL.Enable ( EnableCap.TextureRectangle);

GL.Enable (EnableCap.Blend);
GL.BlendFunc (BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
}
```

And Call InitializeOpenGL before Sprite Rendering (or after drawing GUI).